# Design/theme of the website

Tags: discussion, 7-essential, appearance

What should our website look like?  This is a discussion separated from [What should our logo be?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-should-our-logo-be).

Comment: I don't mean to intimidate people, but this is the design chosen by the Web Apps SE: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/559. So do we have complete control over the design? And who designs the site?

Comment: I'm already intimidated. But then, they are the WEB APPS page :)

Answer (score 1):

The design of the final website is part of the process set by the StackExchange team. Once this site passes the 80 day mark or so of the public beta period, [Jin Yang](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/), the official designer for the Area 51 sites, will post his ideas for a design (including screenshots) and start talking to the community about them.

You can see some example of prototype designs already published by Jin for a few of the more mature beta sites:

- [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/design-ideas-for-web-applications-site-updated-with-screenshots)
- [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshots-v2)
- [Cooking](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/design-ideas-for-cooking-site)

Comment: ok so we don't need to worry about this now.